# ¿Cómo dar formato a una fecha en golang?

Tags: go

Tengo que obtener la fecha del día siguiente y eso ya lo tengo

```
t := time.Now()
    dateTomorrow := t.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
```

Después de esto le tengo que dar el formato ddmmyy así sin guiones ni nada y esto no he encontrado como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Go` a diferencia de otros lenguajes, usa otra [forma de codificar](https://go.dev/src/time/format.go) las constantes de formato de fecha:

```
fmt.Println(dateTomorrow.Format("02012006"))
```

El código es literal para `ddmmyyyy` la cadena es `02012006` y no cualquier otra:

```
02: Dia
01: Mes
2006: Año
```

Answer (score 2):

Go es bastante *peculiar* en su formato de fechas.
En tu caso particular, según la [definición de constantes de formatos de Go](https://go.dev/src/time/format.go), el formato sería el siguiente:

Día: `"02"` (`stdZeroDay`)
Mes: `"01"` (`stdZeroMonth`)
Año: `"06"` (`stdYear`)

Haciendo la prueba en el [playground de Go](https://play.golang.com/):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    dateTomorrow := t.AddDate(0, 0, 1) 
    fmt.Println(t.String()) //formateando la fecha 'actual' (según el servidor del playground)
    fmt.Println(dateTomorrow.String()) //fecha del día siguiente
    fmt.Println(t.Format("020106")) //formateando la fecha 'actual'
    fmt.Println(dateTomorrow.Format("020106")) //formateando la fecha del día siguiente
}
```

Salida:

> 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
> 2009-11-11 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
> 101109
> 111109